# How can I connect to a different server in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have base database on one server and other database on another server and we need to connect to it.

How can link them with a stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE link_sv
   @UserName nvarchar(max)='',
   @Password nvarchar(max)='',
   @Server nvarchar(max)='',
   @DataBase nvarchar(max)=''
AS
BEGIN
   -- how do it
   -- select [dbo].tbl1.*,@Server.@DataBase.tblUsers.Name from [dbo].tbl1 inner join @Server.@DataBase.tblUsers on [dbo].tbl1.ID=@Server.@DataBase.tblUsers.ID
 END
 GO
```

How write this procedure?

I use it:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','Data Source=hodb01; UID=MyLogin; PWD=MyPassowrd', 'select top 1 * from HQPMMPRD.dbo.item_master') AS a
```

but SQL Server blocked access to statement

> 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource'.this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server.

My database in host server. I can't access and change security configuration.

Comment: You need to create a linked server.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: this link add server handy.I want add server not handy and authentication is different .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries on SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/enable-Ad-Hoc-Distributed-Queries.aspx), you can use sp_configure to allow such command executions on your server.

But the most accurate way for such data queries, is to [create linked server on SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) database instance.

Then you can use following syntax in your SQL scripts

```
INSERT INTO [linkedserver].dbname.dbo.targetTable
SELECT column1, columnN FROM sourceTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the  Linked Servers. **Follow these steps**

1. Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> New Linked Server
2. Provide Remote Server Name.
3. Select Remote Server Type (SQL Server).
4. Select Security -> 
       login and password of remote server.

**OR,
You can add linked server using query.**

```
sp_addlinkedserver [ @server= ] 'server' [ , [ @srvproduct= ] 'product_name' ] 
     [ , [ @provider= ] 'provider_name' ]
     [ , [ @datasrc= ] 'data_source' ] 
     [ , [ @location= ] 'location' ] 
     [ , [ @provstr= ] 'provider_string' ] 
     [ , [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' ]
```

**You have to create linked server only once. After creating linked server, we can query it as follows:**

```
select * from LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.OwnerName.TableName
```